# Position of a character each field

Tags: perl, awk, nawk

How can I represent the position of 1 (considering only the 1s after the colon) in the word from field5 and above; counting from right to left.

Input:

```
TT-124 06-03-14 08-02-10 FAS   CAT1:10
TT-125-1 05-03-14 10-06-08 CAS   CAT2:1010 FAT1:10000
TT-125-3 07-03-14 11-02-06 FAS   FAT1:1101
SS-120-1 05-03-14 09-04-07 FAS   CAT3:100000
AA-121-0 06-03-14 08-03-06 CAS   FAT2:11 CAT1:101100
```

Output:

```
TT-124 06-03-14 08-02-10 FAS   CAT1:1
TT-125-1 05-03-14 10-06-08 CAS   CAT2:3 CAT2:1 FAT1:4
TT-125-3 07-03-14 11-02-06 FAS   FAT1:0 FAT1:2 FAT1:3
SS-120-1 05-03-14 09-04-07 FAS   CAT3:5
AA-121-0 06-03-14 08-03-06 CAS   FAT2:0 FAT2:1 CAT1:2 CAT1:3 CAT1:5
```

I have tried below script (as suggested by someone) which works in cygwin, but does not work on Solaris 10 using nawk or /usr/xpg4/bin/awk
How can I implement in solaris?

```
awk '{for(i = 5; i <= NF; i++) {split($i, a, ":"); $i = ""; split(a[2], b, "");
  for(j = 1; j <= length(b); j++) {if(b[j] == 1)
    {$i = ($i == "") ? (a[1] ":" length(b) - j) : ($i FS a[1] ":" length(b) - j)}}};
  print $0}' file
```

Comment: Your position numbers do not match. `FAT2: 11` should be `FAT2:1 FAT2:2`, for example. Have I misunderstood your question, or did you not present a correct example?

Comment: Also, what format is your input? Fixed width, tab delimited?

Comment: capture the # of elems of `b` when you do the split, i.e. `n=split(a[2],b,}})` and use `n` in your `for` loop controls. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drawback of using a one-liner that looks like that (quite illegible) written by someone else is that it is incredibly hard for you to fix when it breaks. I've written some Perl code that should be easier to understand and easier for you to maintain.

It basically splits your string using a regex which is hardcoded to first ignore (match and print) 4 space separated fields of data, then extract the relevant data after it. This could be made a lot more specific, but you have failed to specify what format your data has, if any, so this is the most specific I would make it for now.

Then it takes the first element of the `@-` array `$-[0]` to find the position of each `1` in the numeric string of each target string, and build new strings based on the name, and each numeric match.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($pre, $data) = /^((?:\S+\s+){4})(.+)/;   # capture using regex
    print $pre;                                  # print original prefix string
    my @list;
    for (split ' ', $data) {                     # the list of CAT2:11 pairs
        my ($name, $num) = split /:/;            # separate name and number
        $num = reverse $num;                     # reverse order of numbers
        while ($num =~ /1/g) {                   # extract position of each "1" 
            push @list, "$name:$-[0]";           # make the new string with name
        }
    }
    print "@list\n";                             # print list separated by space
}

__DATA__
TT-124 06-03-14 08-02-10 FAS   CAT1:10
TT-125-1 05-03-14 10-06-08 CAS   CAT2:1010 FAT1:10000
TT-125-3 07-03-14 11-02-06 FAS   FAT1:1101
SS-120-1 05-03-14 09-04-07 FAS   CAT3:100000
AA-121-0 06-03-14 08-03-06 CAS   FAT2:11 CAT1:101100
```

**Output:**

```
TT-124 06-03-14 08-02-10 FAS   CAT1:1
TT-125-1 05-03-14 10-06-08 CAS   CAT2:1 CAT2:3 FAT1:4
TT-125-3 07-03-14 11-02-06 FAS   FAT1:0 FAT1:2 FAT1:3
SS-120-1 05-03-14 09-04-07 FAS   CAT3:5
AA-121-0 06-03-14 08-03-06 CAS   FAT2:0 FAT2:1 CAT1:2 CAT1:3 CAT1:5
```

**Usage:**

To try the code out, change the file handle `<DATA>` to `<>` and use:

```
perl script.pl input.txt > output.txt
```

Redirecting to output file is optional, of course.

Comment: Good solution and thank you for putting in comments. I'm trying to learn `perl` and this helps alot. Though one minor alteration is needed. `push @list, "$name:" . pos($num);` is pushing position from left to right. OP is looking to identify positioning from right to left. +1 none the less.

Comment: @jaypal Oh, that makes his sample more logical then. Thanks for the notification.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Whenever you get a chance, can you please provide some details on `$name:$-[0]`. I was trying to loop over the array to find the index where value is `1`, but this is way better.

Comment: You can read perldoc perlvar, or type `perldoc -v "@-"` in your prompt for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $line (<DATA>) {
  my @args = split /\s+/, $line;

  foreach my $arg (@args) {
    if (not $arg =~ /([A-Z]+\d+)\:([0-1]+)/) {
      print "$arg ";
      next;
    }

    my @bits = split //, $2;
    my $j = $#bits;
    for my $i (0 .. $#bits) {
      print "$1:$j " if $bits[$i];
      $j--;
    }

  }
  print "\n";
}

__DATA__
TT-124 06-03-14 08-02-10 FAS   CAT1:10
TT-125-1 05-03-14 10-06-08 CAS   CAT2:1010 FAT1:10000
TT-125-3 07-03-14 11-02-06 FAS   FAT1:1101
SS-120-1 05-03-14 09-04-07 FAS   CAT3:100000
AA-121-0 06-03-14 08-03-06 CAS   FAT2:11 CAT1:101100
```

#### Output:

```
TT-124 06-03-14 08-02-10 FAS CAT1:1 
TT-125-1 05-03-14 10-06-08 CAS CAT2:3 CAT2:1 FAT1:4 
TT-125-3 07-03-14 11-02-06 FAS FAT1:3 FAT1:2 FAT1:0 
SS-120-1 05-03-14 09-04-07 FAS CAT3:5 
AA-121-0 06-03-14 08-03-06 CAS FAT2:1 FAT2:0 CAT1:5 CAT1:3 CAT1:2
```

Comment: A handy way to deal with input is to use the `__DATA__` whatchamacallit, which allows you to read from the input handle `DATA` in your own source code.

Answer (score 1):

Your input data isn't consistent with your required output. You say you want `CAT2:3 CAT2:1` for the second line, but that is not in right-to-left order, and doesn't match the other lines of output, so I assume that is a mistake.

I think this program is what you need. It expects a path to the input file as a parameter on the command line, and prints the output to STDOUT.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {

  my @fields = split;

  for (my $i = $#fields; $i >= 4; --$i) {
    my ($prefix, $suffix) = split /:/, $fields[$i];
    my @positions;
    push @positions, length($suffix) - $-[0] - 1 while $suffix =~ /1/g;
    my @expansions = map "$prefix:$_", reverse @positions;
    splice @fields, $i, 1, @expansions;
  }

  print "@fields\n";
}
```

**output**

```
TT-124 06-03-14 08-02-10 FAS CAT1:1
TT-125-1 05-03-14 10-06-08 CAS CAT2:1 CAT2:3 FAT1:4
TT-125-3 07-03-14 11-02-06 FAS FAT1:0 FAT1:2 FAT1:3
SS-120-1 05-03-14 09-04-07 FAS CAT3:5
AA-121-0 06-03-14 08-03-06 CAS FAT2:0 FAT2:1 CAT1:2 CAT1:3 CAT1:5
```